# Using a loop to edit items in a list

Tags: python, loops

I have items in a list that have more than 30 characters. I would like to loop through the whole list to make each item 30 characters maximum. I used this code to change the first item in the list manually to give me this result:

```
sites = [
    '520 Slick Boat Ramp (Banana Riv',
    'Eau Gallie Pier (Indian River)',
    'Geiger Point; Melbourne Causeway at (Indian River)',
    'Kelly Park (Banana River)',
    'NASA Causeway; SE side of (Indian River)',
    'Parrish Park Boat Ramp (Indian River)',
    'Port St. John Boat Ramp (Indian River)',
    'Ramp Road Park Boat Ramp (Banana River)'
]


sites[0]=sites[0][0:31]
```

Comment: What loop have you tried so far and what were your results?

Comment: Did you try a for loop?

Comment: `sites = [s[:30] for s in sites]`  (note: the expression s[0:31] you used before trims it to 31 characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply chop each string off at 30 characters, you can do something like this:

```
for s in sites:
    sites[sites.index(s)] = s[:30]
```

or

```
sites = [s[:30] for s in sites]
```

(thanks Iguagangaut)

If you want to filter the list so that only strings that are *already* less than 30 characters long, you can do

```
sites = filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 30, sites)
```

Edit:
As John Coleman said, using `sites.index(s)` isn't really efficient, so if you want to use a for loop, it may be better to use the method described by Błotosmętek:

```
for i in range(let(sites)):
    sites[i] = sites[i[:30]]
```

Comment: That way of doing a for-loop makes it quadratic since `sites.index(s)` is an implicit inner loop. If you are using indices, then the simple `for i in range(len(sites)):` is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible approaches. The most elegant one is in the comment by Iguananaut, and uses a list comprehension. If, however, for whatever reasons you don't want to use list comprehension, you need to use a for loop, either like this:

```
for i in range(len(sites)):
   sites[i] = sites[i][:30]
```

or this:

```
for i, s in enumerate(sites):
    sites[i] = s[:30]
```

While the first approach is more common, the second is considered more Pythonic. According to my tests it is also slightly faster, but that may depend on Python version.